# Button not firing on MVC form when using JavaScript validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 form on  MVC application. The first form is working find (validation and button firing). The second form the validation works but the input button is not firing. When I remove the JavaScript everything works fine Any idea  where I am going wrong. My sample code below
View

Form 1

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Corporate", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype 
     = "multipart/form-data" , id= QuickMEssage}))
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <div class="form-group">
   @Html.Label("Message Body", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2  required" })
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <textarea rows="6" cols="50" name="MessageBody" class="required" id="MessageBody" placeholder="Message Body Not more than 148 characters"></textarea>                                
  </div>
 </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-success" name="quicksend" />
 }
```

Form 2

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BulkMessage", "Corporate", FormMethod.Post, new { 
 enctype = "multipart/form-data" , id= "BulkMessage" }))
 {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <div class="form-group">
   @Html.Label("Message Body", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2  required" })
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <textarea rows="6" cols="50" name="MessageBody" class="required" id="MessageBody" placeholder="Message Body Not more than 148 characters"></textarea>                                
  </div>
 </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Shedule Message" class="btn btn-success" />
  }
```

Controller

```
// Controller for the first form
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string[] mobilenumber, int 
 ddlshedule, string date, int? sendmessage, string MessageBody)
  {
    return View();
  }

  // Controller for the second form. Validation is working fine

 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public async Task<ActionResult> BulkMessage(int ddlshedule, string date, 
  string MessageBody2, HttpPostedFileBase attachmentcsv)
  {
    // This part of the code is not firing
    Return View();
  }
```

JavaScript

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/datatablecss")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/table")
  JavaScript for form 1
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#QuickMEssage").validate();    
 });
```

```
   JavaScript for form 2
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#BulkMessage").validate();
      });

    </script>
  }
```

Comment: Have you seen any errors in the F12 developer tools console? Use the Network trace also to see if you are getting a 500 error back when submitting one route. One thing I noticed right away though is form 2 doesn't appear to have the right form fields to match the route parameters. BulkMessage has an int parameter expected, but with no ddlshedule being passed this will blow up because you can't cast null to int.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for your reply I did not want to put all the code.  ddlshedule is available in my code. I also used F12 for debugging and I cannot see any error in console

Comment: What are you doing? You do NOT call `.validate` is you have included the `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` plugins (i.e. your `jqueryval` bundle). And you have no MVC validation (there are no `data-val-*` attributes because you did not use `@Html.TextAreaFor(...)`. All you have is a `required` attribute which is HTML-5 client side validation only, and is disabled if you have included the validation scripts.

Comment: I suggest you start with [Adding Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation) to learn the basics